# The request failed with HTTP status 401: authorized for access sharepoint web service from C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I hit the following error:

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

**The Code**

The code is as follows:

```
    protected void Execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        /*Declare and initialize a variable for the Lists Web service.*/
        //Web_Reference.Lists myservice = new Web_Reference.Lists();
        ListsWebService.Lists myservice = new ListsWebService.Lists();

        /*Authenticate the current user by passing their default 
        credentials to the Web service from the system credential 
        cache. */
        myservice.Credentials =
           System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        /*Set the Url property of the service for the path to a subsite. Not setting this property will return the lists in the root Web site.*/
        //listService.Url = "http://Server_Name/Subsite_Name/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        myservice.Url = "http://teamsites.ntu.edu.sg/sce/hrdev/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

        try
        {
            /*Declare an XmlNode object and initialize it with the XML 
            response from the GetListCollection method. */
            System.Xml.XmlNode node = myservice.GetListCollection();

            /*Loop through XML response and parse out the value of the
            Title attribute for each list. */
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xmlnode in node)
            {
                Label1.Text += xmlnode.Attributes["Title"].Value + "\n";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            Label1.Text = excep.Message;
        }


    }
```

**IIS Settings** - Only Windows Authentication is Enabled.

**Web.Config file**

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bxxxxxxxx9" >
        <section name="ReadSharePointList.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bxxxxxxxx9" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ListsSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://mainsite/subsite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap"
            contract="StaffRole.ListsSoap" name="ListsSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
<applicationSettings>
    <ReadSharePointList.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="ReadSharePointList_ListsWebService_Lists" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://mainsite/subsite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </ReadSharePointList.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Where could I be missing?

Comment: Looks like your adding service reference like you do with WCF service. You should add as "Add web service reference" for the asmx service.

Comment: @Flowerking, yes, I already add it as "Add web service reference".

Answer (score 0):

As you have only "Windows authentication" enabled on server side, try changing the config as below:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
                 realm="" />
```

Comment: Looking at your config, I suupose you referenced the lists service twice. One as wcf reference and one as web reference?! If so, get rid of the wcf reference and rebuild the solution to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Is your C# ASP.NET running on the same physical server as SharePoint?

If so then its a good chance its the ["Local Loopback Check"](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your ASP.Net page is in the same intranet you can use the System.Net.CredentialCache approach. See Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134614(v=office.14).aspx

If your ASP.Net page is not hosted in the same intranet, you need to get past the authentication provider of the Sharepoint site. See Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177(v=office.14).aspx